# How can I plug my HDMI device into a VGA input

Tags: hdmi, vga, boxee

I want to purchase a Boxee Box which only has an HDMI output. I have a plasma screen which only has a VGA input. What cable(s) do I need to convert the Boxee HDMI output to the VGA input? Is there a single HDMI-VGA cable? Can I go HDMI to DVI to VGA? Do I need a conversion box to go HDMI to VGA (and if so, where can I find one)? Thanks!

Comment: "and if so, where can I find one" -- Note that SuperUser is not for shopping recommendations.

Comment: You'll need [one of these](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=hdmi+to+vga+conver&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hdmi+to+vga+converter#hl=en&safe=off&prmdo=1&tbs=shop:1&&sa=X&ei=jVsWTfzIGoX_nAeJkOnZDQ&ved=0CHIQBSgA&q=hdmi+to+vga+cable&spell=1&biw=1360&bih=643&fp=20da5186f0f95fb1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no easy way to convert HDMI to VGA, as VGA is an analog signal. What this means is the powered digital signal of HDMI has to be actively converted to VGA's analog signal. On amazon you can see plenty of 10 dollar "conversion chords" that claim to convert for you. THIS IS A SCAM. somebody has simply glued a VGA connector to an HDML cable. THESE CANNOT POSSIBLY WORK.

The only way to convert HDMI to VGA is with a powered converter box like those you can see on http://vgatohdmi.com/ (found by google, I do not endorse them as I have no experience with their product). Even when using the converter box you may still run into another problem: HDMI signals are encrypted for DRM. The converter will not decrypt the HDMI signal, so you may have trouble with that. I am not aware of whether or not Boxee encrypts the output, however if they do not then you will be able to use the converter.

-Z

Answer (score 1):

What kind of plasma do you have that doesn't have HDMI?  The cheapest way is probably what you mentioned (going HDMI -> DVI -> VGA).  The picture will look like crap though and it won't carry any audio.  Why not get a receiver that has HDMI in and various options for out?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to go from hdmi to vga will be a converter box . Converting an analog signal to a digital one can get really complicated . Either get an updated tv with an hdmi input or get a converter box . They should be no more than $60

Answer (score 0):

Most Plasma displays built in the last 10 years will have a DVI input, and HDMI and DVI video signals are compatible without conversion. So if you have an available DVI input, you can convert the video from HDMI to DVI without active conversion, but previous posts about encryption and integrated audio would still apply.  A DVI TV/Monitor input is not going to be capable of decryption of HDMI signals (if encrypted with HDCP), and DVI has no concept of audio so if the Boxee unit has no other audio output you will be unable to hear audio.

If in fact you have to convert to VGA, then an active converter is your only hope, and all the sames encryption and audio challenges still exist.