# How to set up 2 unique VGA monitors?

Tags: hdmi, vga

I have [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883101085) desktop, which has 1 VGA and 1 HDMI output ports, and two monitors with VGA inputs. If I get a HDMI to VGA converter, will I be able to have 2 unique screens, or will I just show duplicate screen unless I get some extra hardware?

Comment: You should be able to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Related/Possible dupe: [How can I plug my HDMI device into a VGA input](http://superuser.com/questions/225721/how-can-i-plug-my-hdmi-device-into-a-vga-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a HDMI to VGA adapter should do what you want.  There is no technical reason you can't have two different monitors connected via VGA to that desktop.  Several different adapters are available, [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008O7RH5C) has good reviews and is less than $20.

Sample Adapter:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your PC supports [dual monitors](http://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx2IWJIQUA2OAK7/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B00K0K9PEM) onboard.

If you have two VGA monitors, you'll need an adapter similar to [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008O7RH5C) for the second screen.

Once they're both installed, Windows should recognize both screens and give you options for extending your desktop to the second screen or duplicating the first monitor.